# Promoting a sub-sheet with variants up the hierarchy in Altium

Tags: altium

Let's suppose I have three sheets, Connector1.schdoc, Connector2.schdoc, and Connector3.schdoc.  Each sheet has an instance of the sub-sheet InputFilter.schdoc, which has something simple like an RC filter on it.  Complicating things a bit, one instance of the sub-sheet InputFilter.schdoc uses different parts, and the whole board is already laid out.

I'd like to get rid of the sub-sheets and have all the components on their respective parent sheets, but I figure if I copy and paste it the layout will get torn up.  Is there a way to do an inverse refactor, basically the opposite of "Moving Selected Sub-Circuitry to a Different Sheet" from the documentation [here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/design-refactoring-ad?version=19.1#!moving-selected-sub-circuitry-to-a-different-sheet), and preserve the layout and component variants?

I'm on Altium 19.1.

Comment: Are these the only multiply replicated sheets in your design?

Comment: It's a fully hierarchical project, so there are others.  I didn't want to complicate the description too much.

Answer (score 0):

Use copy and then Edit -> "smart paste".
Select "Paste as themselve".
By this you do not loose the designator or the UUID and the sync to the PCB should work without changes on the PCB.